# Advice needed to understand an example in Characters and representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading [Representations and characters of groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052100392X) by James Gordon and Martin Liebeck.

I would like to clarify on some concepts in an example given on pg 47. Here is an excerpt:

> Let $C_3=\left<a:a^3=1\right>$. Then there is a representation $\rho$ of $C_3$ given by $\rho(a)=  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Let $V$ be a $2$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C},$ with basis $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2\},$ then we turn $V$ into $\mathbb{C}C_3$ module, in particular, by defining $v_1a=v_2$ and $ v_2a=-v_1-v_2$. 
>   Hence, $[a]_\mathbb{\mathcal{B}}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$ If $\mathbb{\mathcal{B'}}=\{u_1(=v_1),  u_2(=v_1+v_2)\}$ is another basis, then $[a]_\mathcal{B'}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

May I know if $[a]_\mathcal{B'}$ is defined as $ \begin{pmatrix} [(u_1a)]_{\mathcal{B'}}   \\ [(u_1a)]_{\mathcal{B'}} \end{pmatrix},$ where $[(u_ia)]_{\mathcal{B'}}$ is the coordinate vector of $u_ia$ relative to $\mathcal{B'} \ ?$

The authors go on to claim that:

> If $T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0   \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix},$ then $[g]_{\mathcal{B}}=T^{-1}[g]_{\mathcal{B'}}T, \forall g \in C_3.$

May I know how is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0   \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ obtained?

Based on my understanding, if we let $I:V \to V$ be the identity map, then $T = \begin{pmatrix} [I(v_1)]_{\mathcal{B'}}    \\ [I(v_2)]_{\mathcal{B'}}  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0   \\ -1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ since $I(v_1)=1\cdot u_1+0 \cdot u_2$ and $I(v_2)=-1\cdot u_1 + 1 \cdot u_2$ and similarly, $T^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} [I(u_1)]_{\mathcal{B}}    \\ [I(u_2)]_{\mathcal{B}}  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0   \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}.$

May I know if my understanding is correct?

Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just what is known as "change of basis" in linear algebra - you can look this up in wikipedia or any linear algebra text for more details.

Note that James and Liebeck use in their book the convention that the matrix of a linear map is written on the rows instead of columns. So here the first row of $T$ is $u_1$ written in basis $\mathcal{B}$ and second row is $u_2$ is written in basis $\mathcal{B}$. Since $u_1 = v_1$ and $u_2 = v_1 + v_2$, you get $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ as the rows.

Comment: Noted, thank you. Is the $T$ that I have written correct as well?